# how to avoid cross-mapping in SQL query while using 2 lists with IN opeartor?

Tags: t-sql

I have a table HistoryRecords which has two columns recordName and timeStamp. I have to delete the records based on both of these. I had used the following query to delete 2 records <'abc', '2010/10/20 19:39:20.0'> and <'def', '2010/10/25 17:43:3.0'> :

```
DELETE FROM HistoryRecords WHERE (recordName IN (N'abc',N'def') AND timeStamp IN (N'2010/10/20 19:39:20.0',N'2010/10/25 17:43:3.0'))
```

The problem is that the above query leads to deletion of other records also like <'abc', '2010/10/25 17:43:3.0'> because the list of recordNames contains 'abc' and list of timestamp contains '2010/10/25 17:43:3.0'.

Please let me know any approach that will prevent this extra unintended deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You should seprate cases. Dont combine

delete from historyRecords
where (recName='abc' and timeStamp='2010...19:39')
OR
(recName='def' and timeStamp='2010...17:43')

Comment: that would work fine but would be the impact on the performance as compared to the original query as my actual scenario requires bulk deletion of lacs of records.

(Further, if you could tell me the max possible length of a query in SQL-Server 2008 as ur solution will cause the query length to increase manifolds for the same no. of input records).